# Search based upon tag value

Tags: search

While performing a search in SharePoint is it possible to search based upon tag values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search indexer does take into account tags when searching for content.  With that said, there is no out of the box search solution to search only based on tags.  You could either write a custom search solution or use a third-party solution.